# ASP.NET Control Cannot Find Child Control in SharePoint Web Part

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, user-controls

Host is SharePoint 2010, Using VS2010 .NET 3.5. I have custom ASCX controls living in Web Parts. The controls inherit from a POCO class that inherits from System.Web.UI.UserControl. This control has the following code:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs evArgs)
        {
            var myliteral = Page.FindControl("myliteral");
            base.OnPreRender(evArgs);
        }
```

and every .ascx has this content:

```
<asp:Literal ID="myliteral" runat="server" Visible="false"><br /></asp:Literal>
```

I set a breakpoint to see if "myliteral" in the C# code would have a reference to the generated control, but it does not, it is coming out null. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you **have** to use .NET 4.0? SharePoint 2010 is built on .NET 3.5 and using newer versions will only cause problems / will not work.

Comment: OK, set to .NET 3.5. The issue still exists. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Page.FindControl` doesn't look recursively in nested containers, so if `myLiteral1` is in ascx used by webpart.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.90).aspx